# Should a oscillator's output load capacitor be attached to ground? And how much?

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I have some experience with electrical engineering but there are various subjects I'm totally a noob at.

I'm planning on using the ASE-24.000MHZ-ET and it states that the Output Load should be 15pF

Should this load be connected like this?

[image: Schematic]

Or should the C1151 capacitor be in series with the CLK output? Also if I recall correctly, the length of the trace also affects the total pF load on the line. Is this something I should take into calculation on a small 8x8cm PCB?

Thanks!

Comment: The trace capacitance probably isn't large enough to worry about but the capacitance of the input the clock goes to may be, that will typically be in the 15pF range. Also it's fairly standard practice to use a pull up resistor on the mode pin rather than tying it directly to the power rail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it states that the Output Load should be 15pF

No, it does not say the output load should be 15 pF - it says that the maximum load should be 15 pF: -

[image]

Get rid of the 15 pF.

Comment: Thank you! I totally misread that. I'll just connect BCLK straight into the BCLK pin of the chip